# Does "Home sweet home" phrase carry any negative meaning in British and American English?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

According to Oxford Dictionary, which is a British Dictionary:

> **[home sweet home](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/home_1#home_idmg_6)**: ​(often ironic) used to say how pleasant your home is (especially when you really mean that it is not pleasant at
> all)

But according to Merriam Webster (which is an American Dictionary),

> [home sweet home](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home%20sweet%20home): idiom:  —used when one returns home after being away
> to say that one is happy to be home

Do British people say "**home sweet home**" with a negative meaning while American people don't?

Comment: Oxford does not say that the ironic usage is mainly British. It just offers a slightly more complete explanation than Merriam=Webster does in this case.

Comment: There is nothing inherently negative about the idiom.

Comment: Most expressions can be used sarcastically/ironically. If you returned home to find your kids had messed it up, you might say "home sweet home" in an ironic way, but if you returned home and everything was neat and tidy, you might use it in a genuine way. If you indicate where you have seen it or where you want to use it, that might help deduce if it would be seen as sarcastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression comes from [a sentimental song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home!_Sweet_Home!) from the 1820s which was very popular in the 19th century. Because it is so well-known it has become something of a [cliché](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cliche), so it is sometimes used ironically.